# How to open Node.js command prompt?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, node.js

I have completed installed Ruby on Rails on my ubuntu system. I have try to search the node.js but not found. May anybody help me how to open node.js cmd prompt in ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed node.js with `apt-get install nodejs` then it is simply `node`.

**STEPS :**

1. Install node.js through `apt-get install nodejs`
2. write `aptitude search 'nodejs'` on terminal. If aptitude not installed then write `sudo apt-get install aptitude` to install aptitude. Then again write `aptitude search 'nodejs'` on terminal.
3. `i   nodejs` shows next to it. It means that you have successfully installed.
4. Enter `nodejs` on terminal; `<` shows. It means that `nodejs` cmd line started.